# View.GONE leaves empty space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I get 2 types of data with Firebase and with RadioButton I sort the displayed data. Everything seems to work, but still there is an empty space when one of the data types is hidden. Tell me how to hide / show data correctly.

[That's what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khias.png)

**Adapter:**

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case Person.PersonType.TYPE_1:
            View userType1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.driver_row, parent, false);
            return new PersonType1ViewHolder(userType1);
        case Person.PersonType.TYPE_2:
            View userType2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.fare_row, parent, false);
            return new PersonType2ViewHolder(userType2);
    }
    return super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
}

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, 
Person model,
                                  int position) {
    if (viewHolder instanceof PersonType1ViewHolder) {
        ((PersonType1ViewHolder) viewHolder).time.setText("Full time: " + 
model.getTime());
        if (activate) {
            viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return;
    }
    if (viewHolder instanceof PersonType2ViewHolder) {
        ((PersonType2ViewHolder) viewHolder).time.setText("Full time2: " + 
model.getTime());
        if (activate2) {
            viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
private class PersonType1ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView time;
    PersonType1ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
    }
}

private class PersonType2ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView time;
    PersonType2ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time_two);
    }
}
```

Row layouts are the same - wrap_content

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_trip_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/radio_button_group" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_trip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="addTrip"
        android:text="add" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/add_trip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_all"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="all" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_driver"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="driver" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_fare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="fare" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: We need to see the XML, the java looks correct the bug must be in the XML layout,

Comment: yup, code looks fine, maybe ur xml is the problem

Comment: xml like ordinary

Comment: can you post the code where itemView is populated - the two `ViewHolder` implementations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don’t know how correct this is, but I just programmatically set the parameters

```
viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered issue like this, turns out it's the problem with the override method `getItemCount()` in the adapter. I guess if you specified the number of `getItemCount()`, RecyclerView will reserve a place for the ViewHolder even if you hide it. This is the code of how i solve it.

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    when {
        !importantImages.isNullOrEmpty() && !otherImages.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> Important.ordinal
                else -> Other.ordinal
            }
        }
        otherImages.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
            return Important.ordinal
        }
        importantImages.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
            return Other.ordinal
        }
    }
    return 0
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (ViewType.values()[viewType]) {
        Important -> {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_important_list, parent, false)
            ImportantViewHolder(layoutInflater)
        }
        Other -> {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_other_list, parent, false)
            OtherViewHolder(layoutInflater)
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = when {
    !importantImages.isNullOrEmpty() && !otherImages.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
        2
    }
    importantImages.isNullOrEmpty() && otherImages.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
        0
    }
    else -> {
        1
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

### 1.Why does it happen?

`viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` This will not work in RecyclerView.

`itemView` is a child view in RecyclerView. Unlike the other ViewGroup (FrameLayout,etc), RecyclerView ignores childen's visibility during layout process.

### 2.How to solve it?

**Option1**  Use a regular view group such as FrameLayout to wrap your real layout, and hide your real layout: `findViewById(R.id.layout_to_hide).setVisibility(View.GONE)`

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_to_hide"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         //Put here your views
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Option2** Change the itemView’s heigh to 0 so we can't see it

```
holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

**Option3**  If this item shouldn't be in List, then simply don't let it in adapter data, or remove it.

### 3.Learn more

**1. Why the other view group such as FrameLayout works fine with children's visibibilty?**

They don't compute the child's layout params if it's GONE

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2. Why RecyclerView doesn't?**

RecyclerView still compute the child's layout params if it's GONE so it still occupies spaces.

[image: recycler view]

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too, I found that if add a container outside with wrap_content, then it works.

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/v_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

In java code:

```java
v_root.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

v_root in code means your old view root.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. 
But I can assure you that with `View.GONE`, the view becomes invisible without leaving spaces. While with `View.INVISIBLE`, the view leaves an invisible space.
If it doesn't work, it means that something is wrong with your layout.

Comment: I also do not understand why this does not work, but it is. Therefore, I asked a question

Comment: Try changing RelativeLayout to LinearLayout in row layout.